# jQuery class selectors with nested div's

Tags: jquery

This is part of some HTML from which I need to retrieve a piece of data. The HTML is assigned to a variable called fullDescription.

```
<p>testing</p>
<div class="field field-type-text field-field-video-short-desc">
    <div class="field-label">Short Description:&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item odd">
                Demonstrates the basics of using the Content section of App Cloud Studio        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field field-type-text field-field-video-id">
    <div class="field-label">Video ID:&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item odd">
                    1251462871001        
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wish to retrieve the video ID number (1251462871001).  I was thinking something like this:

```
var videoID = $(fullDescription).find(".field.field-type-text.field-field-video-id").find(".field-item.odd").html();
```

Although it does not generate any syntax errors, it does not retrieve the number.

Thanks for helping out a jQuery noob!

-Matt

Comment: "The HTML is assigned to a variable called fullDescription." You mean fullDescription is a string ? Are you trying to use jQuery's tree traversal functions on a string ?

Comment: Yes, fullDescription is a string.  For instance (with help from stackoverflow) I retrieved the short description using $(fullDescription).find( ".field-item.odd" ).html();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need so many selectors, try:

```
var videoID = $(fullDescription).find(".field-field-video-id .field-item.odd").html();
```

I was lazy and my above code was just to show you don't need so many selectors. After spending some time to figure this out, I have a solution:

```
var videoID = $(fullDescription).filter('.field-field-video-id').find('.odd').html();
```

Filter is the best way in jQuery to sort through a string that is actually HTML. Once you have that, you're dealing with an HTML object and can use find.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to do a find. The code here http://jsbin.com/welcome/54447/ shows a working example.

This code will give you the value of the div you are interested in.

```
$('.field-field-video-id .field-items .field-item.odd').html();
```

Is your 'fullDescription' variable just a string or a jQuery object? If it is a jquery object you can pass it to the selector above like so

```
$('.field-field-video-id .field-items .field-item.odd', fullDescription).html();
```

If fullDescription is a string, pass in $(fullDescription) above.

Comment: Obviously this code works (thanks for the working example).  The fullDescription variable is a string.  I hate to be dense, but I am not sure what syntax to use when you say "pass in $(fullDescription)".  I tried a few variations, but not the correct one.

Comment: Have an answer above, but would still like to see how this works

Comment: Hi, sorry about the confusion. You can use the syntax I mentioned when you have the items in the DOM - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ (as shown in the first option, the second parameter is the context). When all you have is a string containing HTML you need to use the find() method.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like:

```
$('div.field field-type-text field-field-video-id div.field-items div.field-item.odd', fulldescription);
```

This will get nested divs with the given classes. When you do not have a space between the statements it means that this should be for one element.(one element should be a div and have classes field, field-type-text etc). When the space is parsed, it means that this must be a child of the item(s) matching the first part. When finally specifying the fulldescription, it means search in the context of fulldescription

Comment: This returns a jQuery object, which I am not sure what to do with

Comment: well, you can do a .htlm() to get the html of the element.